# TemplateDoesNotExist at /join/home.html (Django)

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-settings

I've went through the other answers here but can't grasp how to fix my version of this problem since this is my first project. I can get 127.0.0.1:8000/admin to show up just fine.

I'm getting this error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /join/home.html.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    /join/home.html.
```

`home.html` is located in `/Users/user/Desktop/mvp_landing/static/templates/join`

In my `views.py` I have this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext

from .models import Join
from .forms import JoinForm


def home(request):
    form = JoinForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_join = form.save(commit=False)
        new_join.save()
    return render_to_response('/join/home.html.', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

so I should be ok with what I have here in `settings.py` for `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, right?:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static", "templates"),
)
```

Here is the entire `settings.py`(with db info, etc removed):

```
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static", "media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static", "static-only")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static", "static"),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)


SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mvp_landing.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mvp_landing.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static", "templates"),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'south',
    'join',
)
```

and `urls.py` is this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    (r'media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^$', 'join.views.home', name='home'),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Most likely it's your extra trailing `.` in your `render_to_respones` call.  `'/join/home.html.'` should be `'/join/home.html'`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Peter. I just removed the extra dot and unfortunately I'm still getting the error. Good catch though. I'm still learning the intricacies of the syntax.

Comment: @ChrisK It'll be the first /

Comment: Thanks Ergusto, that was the culprit. Now if I actually knew that was what I was looking for, I would saved saved myself 3 hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix the path here:

```
return render_to_response('join/home.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Notice how I removed the `/` at the beginning and also the trailing `.`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this is the issue. Like I mentioned above, I don't know much about even the syntax yet, so I was unsure of what to even look for.

Comment: Django's exception page is very informative. You can read `TemplateDoesNotExist at /join/home.html.` so, you may imagine that there's something wrong about the template path you're providing, normally, a `/` at the beginning in Unix-like systems are the root, so the system may be trying to find the template at root `/join/` directory, which don't exist :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first slash in the view template string.